# RANDBETWEEN for SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server

How would you create a function that returns a random number between two number?

example syntax

RandBetween(3,300)

Comment: would be nice if float or int is an option. yes, includes 300.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

How about

- Use `RAND()` (which returns a value between 0 and 1 (exclusive).
- multiply by 298 (since you want a dynamic range of [300-3] = 297 + 1)
- add 3 to Offset
- and cast to INT?

i.e.

```
SELECT CAST(RAND() * 298 + 3 AS INT)
```

[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/3d6954dd72e53b90/1)

(**Edit** Also see @ivo's answer for how to turn this into a user defined function)

Answer (score 3):

Based on the solution of StuartLC, you could also use a Stored Procedure
Like this if you want to reuse your code more often

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[RANDBETWEEN]
@LowerBound int = 0 ,
@UpperBound int = 1 , 
@ret int OUT
AS
    BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SELECT @ret = (CAST((RAND() * (@UpperBound - @LowerBound)) + @LowerBound AS INT));
RETURN ;
END;
```

And Call it like this :

```
DECLARE @tmp INT;
EXECUTE [dbo].[RANDBETWEEN] 0,10, @ret=@tmp OUT ;
SELECT @tmp
```

To Create A Function you must first create a view :

```
CREATE VIEW Get_RAND
AS
SELECT RAND() AS MyRAND
GO
```

Then you can create a function like this (accessing the view with the SELECT MyRand ... ) :

```
CREATE FUNCTION RANDBETWEEN(@LowerBound INT, @UpperBound INT)
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @TMP FLOAT;
    SELECT @TMP = (SELECT MyRAND FROM Get_RAND);
    RETURN CAST(@TMP* (@UpperBound - @LowerBound) + @LowerBound AS INT);
END
GO
```

And finally you can call your function it like this :

```
SELECT [dbo].[RANDBETWEEN](1,10)
```

Comment: Can I do it without a view?

Comment: Thanks. That's really good to know. Instead of using the view, can I use the SP? ie can the function call the SP to get the random value?

Comment: Yes you just create the View once , afterwards you just use the function

Comment: There is a reason why I cannot create a view. Is there a way to do it with sp and a function only?

Comment: I believe this favours the interior numbers and not the boundaries because of the missing .5 from below the LowerBound and the .5 from above the UpperBound. If you run the function across 10s of thousands of iterations, you'll find that the frequency of top and bottom number is roughly 1/2 of what it is for the rest of the numbers.

Answer (score 2):

The range of `rand()` on SQL Server is [0, 1).

If you want to map that into a range of *integers* starting with A and ending with B:

```
-- option #1
declare @rnd int = @B + 1;
while @rnd = @B + 1
    set @rnd = cast(rand() * (@B - @A + 1) + @A as int);

-- option #2
declare @rnd int;
set @rnd = cast(rand() * (@B - @A + 1) + @A as int);
if @rnd = @B + 1 set @rnd = @B;
```

Casting to int truncates but there is still a very slim possibility of the expression evaluating to @B + 1 you'd probably want to handle that by generating a new number or by arbitrarily translating it to another value.

If you want to map that into a range of *reals* starting with A and going up to B (non-inclusive):

```
rand() * (@B - @A) + @A
```

Answer (score 1):

I realize I'm necro'ing an old thread but someone asked a question in the comments of "***There is a reason why I cannot create a view. Is there a way to do it with sp and a function only?***" and no one ever answered that question ( for @Bill ).

The answer is "**Yes**".  The important thing is that you can't use RAND() or NEWID() within the function itself.  Actually, you can, but it requires the use of OPENROWSET and, if you can't create a view, it's not likely they're going to allow you to enable "Ad Hoc Remote Queries" just to use OPENROWSET.

The other thing is that we're trying to create random Integers.  If that's true, why are we bothering with RAND() at all?  It returns FLOAT values and that datatype is a fair bit slower than pure Integer Math.

So, we need to do two things in our function... use only Integer Math and provide a random "seed", which will be in the form of NEWID(), which will produce a (pseudo) random value on its own.  Obviously, to be external without the use of a view or OPENROWSET, we'll need to provide that random "seed" as a parameter to the function.

The details are in the flower box of the code.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.RandBetweenINT
/**************************************************************************************************
 Purpose:
 Returns a Pseudo-Random Integer between two inclusive values WITHOUT needing a view as the source
 of RAND().
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Useage:
--===== Basic syntax for a single value.
 SELECT dbo.RandBetweenINT(@LoINT,@HiINT,NEWID())
;
--===== Basic systax for multiple values.
 SELECT dbo.RandBetweenINT(@LoINT,@HiINT,NEWID())
   FROM SomeSchema.SomeTable
;
--===== Example: Generate 1 million random integers having the value of -10 thru +100 and store 
     -- them in a Temp Table.
   DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #MyHead
;
 SELECT TOP (1000000)
        RandInt = dbo.RandBetweenINT(-10,100,NEWID())
   INTO #MyHead
   FROM      sys.all_columns ac1 --These two tables are being used as a "Pseudo-Cursor" row source
  CROSS JOIN sys.all_columns ac2
;
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Programmer's Notes:
 1. For Pseudo-Randomness, the 3rd parameter must be NEWID().
 2. This is a scalar function, which is slower than an iTVF (Inline Table Valued Function. On the
    box it was developed on, it takes a whopping 4 seconds to execute.  A similar iTVF will take
    something less than 400ms (as test on my box).
 3. If @LoInt > @HiInt, NULLs will be returned.
 4. Note that CHECKSUM(NEWID()) returns a random Integer much more quickly that a conversion of
    NEWID() to a BINARY or VARINARY and also allows for Integer Math.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Revision History:
 Rev 00 - Date Unknown - Jeff Moden - Initial concept
        - Date unknown but have been using the technique for a very long time and eventually 
          published an article about it on 26 March 2012. Here's the URL to the article.
https://www.sqlservercentral.com/forums/topic/generating-test-data-part-1-generating-random-integers-and-floats

 Rev 01 - 20 May 2020 - Jeff Moden 
        - Creation of this function for the following topic.
          https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30601961/randbetween-for-sql-server-2012
**************************************************************************************************/
--===== Define the I/O for this function
        (
         @LoInt INT
        ,@HiInt INT
        ,@NewID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER 
        )
RETURNS INT AS
  BEGIN
 RETURN (SELECT RandInt = ABS(CHECKSUM(@NewID)%(@HiInt-@LoInt+1))+@LoInt
          WHERE @LoInt <= @HiInt) --Safety to prevent silent errors
    END
;
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to adjust the Upper and Lower bounds by .5 in either direction in order to have equal distribution.
If you run the existing function between 1,4 for 4,000 rows, you will get roughly half the frequency of 1s and 4s that you get with 2s and 3s.

So I suggest this repair:

```
    return (select round((((@UPPER+.5)-(@LOWER-.5))*RAND + (@LOWER-.5)),0)
    from vw_rand)
```